# Angular-ui-router state.transitionTo not working outside controller function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm new to angularjs, and try using ui-router for a search page. The code is like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='test'>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <script src='angular.min.js'></script>
    <script src='angular-ui-router.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <a ui-sref='home'>Home</a>
        <a ui-sref='search'>Search</a>
    </nav>
    <div ui-view></div>
```

And the script

```
<script>
var globals = {};
var app = angular.module('test', ['ui.router'])
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function (state, route) {
    route.otherwise('/');
    state.state('home', {
        url: '/',
        template: '<h1>Home</h1>',
        controller: [function () {}]
    }).state('search', {
        url: '/search/:s',
        controller: ['$state', function (state) {
            globals.state = state;
            trans('xyz'); // test, and this is working, when click "Search" first time
        }],
        // want to transition when input changed & blur, but the hash tag remains "xyz"
        template: '<h1>Search</h1><input onchange="trans(this.value)">'
    });
}]);

function trans(x) {
    globals.state.transitionTo('search', {s: x});
    console.log('Transition to', x);
}
</script>
```

I override `onchange` of the `input` and expect that `$state.transitionTo` is called and thus hash tag would be changed when user input something and blur. `transitionTo` is called indeed, but the state remains unchanged.

I also tried typing `globals.state.transitionTo('home')` in the console, but nothing happens.

So does `$state` become invalid outside the controller function? What's the correct way to do that?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/eXR0lbhHevFpDfiwCr6D?p=preview) *(to follow OP scenario, search field losses focus on each change === because redirection and state re-init happens)*

One way, how to get access to `$state` and `$stateParams` is to place them into **`$rootScope`**:

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
  function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
}])
```

And, to make the controller code trans available to our view, we have to use the $scope as well (the essence of angular 1):

```
.state('search', { 
    url: '/search/:s',
    controller: ['$state', '$scope', '$stateParams', function (state, $scope, $stateParams) {
      $scope.search = $stateParams.s;
        globals.state = state;
        //trans('xyz'); // test, and this is working, when click "Search" first time
        $scope.trans = trans;
    }],
    // want to transition when input changed & blur, but the hash tag remains "xyz"
    templateUrl: 'tpl.html' // used more complex stuff, see plunker
});
```

Check that all [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/eXR0lbhHevFpDfiwCr6D?p=preview)

Comment: Enlightening! Thanks very much. A little flaw is that each keypress would make input losing focus. Can be fixed by adding an argument `{notify: false}` to `transitionTo`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use $state outside controllers you can do this:

```
angular.element(document.body).injector().get('$state').transitionTo('home');
```